# How I Print table descending order while use foreach in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I already print the table from SQL DB in my laravel application but I want to print it I descending order.

I already tried.

```
  @foreach( $categories->all()->orderBy('id desc') as $category )
```

But it is not worked.
Help Me!!

```
@foreach( $categories->all() as $category )
<tr>
  <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $category->id }}</td>
  <td>{{ $category->created_at }}</td>
  <td>{{ $category->updated_at }}</td>
  <td>Edit</td>
  <td>Delete</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Use like this: `$categories->all()->orderBy('id', 'desc') `

Comment: Call to a member function orderBy() on array

Comment: this error arise

Comment: $categories->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get(); try this.

Comment: "Call to a member function orderBy() on array"

Comment: Show us the query that gets the `$categories` data.

Comment: https://ibb.co/pRpcmvm This is link of first img

Comment: @ShamsherSidhu the orderByRaw should be `->orderByRaw('(updated_at - created_at) desc')`

Comment: Also why not you are using $categories = Category::orderBy("id", "desc")->get(); ?

Comment: Actually, I was used in a very simple syntax https://stackoverflow.com/a/56303983/9853146

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the `$categories` contains the array. To sort an array you should convert this to collection first and and then run sort on that easily.

like

```
collect($categories)->sortByDesc('id');
```

Here is the documentation for the more details. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortby

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, devs 
It is solved now
With

```
all()
->sortByDesc('id');
```